# Why doesn't Chrome scale up the width/height of a div on page zoom?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, zooming, scale

Try zooming in (using the page zoom feature, e.g. cmd+) this piece of HTML/CSS in Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/W68eL/4/

Now, try the same thing in Chrome.

For some reason, Chrome does not scale up the width/height of the content box, but at the same time scales up the border. I would almost consider this a bug.

Does anyone know of any workarounds?

**Edit:**

I have filed an issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142325), we'll see what the responses are.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. If you specify your border width in pixels rather than Ms it doesn't have the scaling issue.

Comment: It all scales for me in Chrome 17.0.963.79 - the box size and the border. In Chrome 21.0.1180.75 it fails as you describe. It does look like a bug has been introduced.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 21.0.1180.75 m, and the content area does appear to be scaling for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're seeing but it looks like same to me in Chrome and Firefox when I zoom.

Comment: @j08691 To clarify, [this](http://oi46.tinypic.com/23mrhnn.jpg) is what I am seeing on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has to do something with the "em" property. It acts differently for both Firefox and Chrome.

I've taken 20px instead of 1em and then ran it on both the browsers. The effect was same.

Fiddle it: http://jsfiddle.net/W68eL/5/

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I included that info in the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142325) I filed.