# LESS/CSS Ribbon breaks in chrome on resize

Tags: css, google-chrome, zooming, less, ribbon

I have a css/less ribbon that looks fine in Firefox, but breaks in Chrome (upon resize).

It looks fine when viewed at 100% zoom, but moving in or out moves the elements out of alignment. I've put it in a tinkerbin below and made the colors less variables to make it easier to play around with.

NOTE: When using this code on Tinkerbin, you must set the CSS syntax to be LESS and press RUN, otherwise the ribbon won't load at all :)

http://tinkerbin.com/9rMTZgdg

Comment: That is just flat out bizarre. Everything number wise looks fine, everything I check still shows an issue at a couple of zoom levels up or down. I'll have to call it a night for now. Maybe something will come to me in my dreams.

Comment: I know. Before posting I tried everything I could think of. Starting to wonder whether Chrome itself is to blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an unresolved bug (as of 1/13/2013). [Here was another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930483/why-doesnt-chrome-scale-up-the-width-height-of-a-div-on-page-zoom) that narrowed it down to `em` sizing on the border being the issue. That person ended up filing [a bug report with webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94013). Perhaps you should add your experience as confirmation to that bug report.

It does seem confirmed that it is an `em` unit scaling issue in `webkit` (at least Chrome, possibly Safari too). When I switch your code over entirely to `px` measurements (precalculating the sizes based off your `font-size: 16px !important`) then I get a correctly functioning ribbon, [as you can see here](http://tinkerbin.com/WsDSXr1t), that scales just beautifully in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely add that feedback to the bug report.